# Why is there a form in a Wicket modal window?

Tags: wicket

When I look at the HTML of a Wicket modal window, I see a form. Why is it there?

Answer (score 2):

ModalWindow's JavaScript generates a `<form>` to support the following use-case:

```
+ Page
  + Form("f")
    + TextField("a")
    + ModalWindow("m")
      + Form("f2")
        + TextField("b")
```

When rendered in the browser, the nested form "f2" is rendered as a `<div>` - this is something Wicket does for you because nested forms are not valid HTML.

When opened, ModalWindow removes its containing markup and puts it into a `<div>` added to the document body:

```
<form wicket:id="f">
    <input wicket:id="a" />
    <div wicket:id="m">
         <!-- markup removed -->
    </div>
</form>

<div>
   <form> <!-- generated form -->
       <div wicket:id="f2">
           <input wicket:id="b" />
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Without the generated form the inputs inside the modal window could not be submitted via Ajax.

Note that this has a naughty implication:
Even when you just want to use a form inside the modal window, you still have to have a form wrapping the modal window.

Without it:

```
+ Page
  # wrong - no wrapping form
  + ModalWindow("m")
    + Form("f2")
      + TextField("b")
```

... "f2" would stay a `<form>` and the result would invalid HTML with two nested forms:

```
<div wicket:id="m">
     <!-- markup removed -->
</div>

<div>
   <form> <!-- generated form -->
       <form wicket:id="f2">
           <input wicket:id="b" />
       </form>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I find this use case very confusing. Which form will be submitted if I type ENTER key in <input wicket:id="b" /> (or submit it in any other way) ? The one with wicket:id="f" or the auto-generated one? If I need to have a form inside the modal then I'd provide my own <form> around <input wicket:id="b"/>. I guess the auto-generated <form> is to support something like nested forms but I don't think this will work with the HTML in the example above. Is there any magic that will submit both input fields (`a` and `b`) in the same request?

Comment: I added details to my answer. I never liked that ModalWindow generates so much HTML including a <form>, but I never found a better solution to cover all cases.